# USB-C Wall Charger with data ports

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, charging

I have a new MacbookPro with only USB-C ports. Does there exist a wall charger for USB-C that can provide the appropriate power while also providing a sort of built in dongle for USB and an SD card reader?  I am looking for something like the below image, where the extra USB ports also provide data to my mac when plugged in via USB-C. Does such a product exist? I would never need to remember to bring another dongle again, just bring my wall charger.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in a very convenient form factor like that or that include an SD Card Reader. There are some good USB-C Docks that provide connectivity and charging [Kensington SD4600P USB-C Docking Station](http://amzn.to/2oNGpHv) or [CalDigit USB-C Docking Station](http://amzn.to/2oksg0w) but they may not be quite what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Its unfortunate that it doesn't seem to exist yet. It'd be great to not have to bring two cords with me everywhere I go. I'd forget my head if it wasn't attached to me..